# problema en mis condicionales

Tags: python

```
def operacionesCombinadas():
    elegir_operacion=str(input("""que operacion elegiras suma,resta,multiplicacion,division """))
    if elegir_operacion=='+' or 'suma':
        suma()
        print('ahora mas operaciones')
    elif elegir_operacion=='-' or 'resta':
        resta()
        print('¿que operacion elegiras ahora?')
    elif elegir_operacion=='x' or 'multiplicacion':
        multiplicacion()
        print('wow wow')
    elif elegir_operacion=='/' or 'division':
        division()
        print('la ultima que agrgue ¿agregare mas?')
    else:
        print('error')
```

Disculpen por el código espagueti

Al principio creí que todo estaba bien:

```
>>> operacionesCombinadas()                                                                              
que operacion elegiras suma,resta,multiplicacion,division 
suma
introdeuce el numero a sumar
1
introduce el otro numero
1
la suma es 2
ahora mas operaciones
```

Pero después me di cuente de que algo estaba mal:

```
>>> operacionesCombinadas()
que operacion elegiras suma,resta,multiplicacion,division 
fv
introduce el numero a sumar
1
introduce el otro numero
1
la suma es 2
ahora mas operaciones
```

Debería imprimir error en lugar de introduce el numero a sumar ,el otro numero que hice mal en las condicionales.

Comment: El error es que te estás inventando las comparaciones: ` if elegir_operacion=='+' or 'suma':`, qué te hace pensar que si en la primera comparación debes poner una igualdad (==), en la segunda no? ` if elegir_operacion=='+' or elegir_operacion=='suma':` es la forma correcta de escribir esa comparación, no puedes simplemente saltarte la primera parte de la igualdad y esperar que el intérprete sepa qué tiene que poner ahí!

Answer (score 1):

para solucionarlo el condicional tiene que ser de esta forma:

```
if elegir_operacion=='+' or elegir_operacion=='suma':
```

Esto es porque python considera un string no vacío como True, por lo que siempre se ejecuta ese condicional. Al utilizar or en tu código estas diciendo que si la variable elegir_operacion es verdadera o el string suma es verdadero procederá(lo cual siempre ocurre).

Podes probar lo que te digo si hacer un programa como:

```
if 'suma':
    
    print('suma es verdadero')
```

Comment: gracias @Noxven